# Can double generating functions be used to solve this?

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, expectation, generating-functions, closed-form

I was really interested in this question here

[What is the expected number of red apples left when all the green apples are picked?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883733/what-is-the-expected-number-of-red-apples-left-when-all-the-green-apples-are-pic)

> We have 4 green apples and 60 red apples. Each time we pick one out
>   without replacement. Then what is the expected number of red apples
>   left when all 4 green apples are picked?

I tried to use generating functions to get a closed form. I wrote a recurrence for the expected number of red apples like this (and I've verified that it is correct):

$$E(r,g) = \frac{r}{r+g}E(r-1,g) + \frac{g}{r+g}E(r,g-1)$$

and $E(0,g) = 0$ and $E(r,0) = r$.

So I did this

$$G(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \sum_{g=0}^{\infty} E(r,g) x^r y^g$$

and tried expanding it out and shifting indices and taking derivatives but it was a huge mess and I had no confidence in what I was doing. Can generating functions be used here to get the closed form $E(r,g) = \frac{r}{g+1}$? I noticed this pattern by inspection and used induction to prove that the closed form was correct, but I wanted to know how to actually derive it using generating functions.

Comment: One big problem I can see in using this approach is the $(r+g)$ term, as both $r$ and $g$ can be obtained by differentiating the generating function with respect to either $x$ or $y$, but I don't see how to obtain their sum...

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: I've added a corresponding answer.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Ah, I see. I should have thought about that. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[2016-08-13]:**  A different way to proceed from the  PDE in (5), independent of other answers is stated  *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888659/looking-for-a-smart-way-to-solve-a-linear-pde-with-some-nice-symmetries/1890612#1890612)*. Coefficient extraction added at the end of this answer.

---

OPs recurrence relation is fine (if we additionally specify the range of validity) and we can derive a generating function from it.

> We start by recalling the recurrence relation
>   \begin{align*}
> (r+g)E(r,g)&=rE(r-1,g)+gE(r,g-1)\qquad\qquad &r,g\geq 1\tag{1}\\
> E(r,0)&=r &r\geq 0\\
> E(0,g)&=0 &g\geq 0\\
> \end{align*}

In the following we consider each term of the recurrence relation separately. 
It is also convenient to use the *[differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator)* $D_x:= \frac{d}{dx}$ and $D_y:=\frac{d}{dy}$.

> With the Ansatz
>   \begin{align*}
> G(x,y)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{g=0}^\infty E(r,g)x^ry^g
> \end{align*}
>
> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=1}^\infty&\sum_{g=1}^\infty(r+g)E(r,g)x^ry^g\tag{2}\\
> &=(xD_x+yD_y)\sum_{r=1}^\infty\sum_{g=1}^\infty E(r,g)x^ry^g\tag{3}\\
> &=(xD_x+yD_y)\left(G(x,y)-\sum_{g=0}^\infty E(0,g)y^g-\sum_{r=0}^\infty E(r,0)x^r+E(0,0)\right)\\
> &=(xD_x+yD_y)\left(G(x,y)-\sum_{r=0}^\infty rx^r\right)\\
> &=(xD_x+yD_y)\left(G(x,y)-(xD_x)\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\
> &=(xD_x+yD_y)G(x,y)-(xD_x)^2\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we have to respect the validity of the recurrence relation and start with $r=g=1$ accordingly
- In (3) we use the operator $(xD_x)$ to transform a series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty a_r x^r$ to $\sum_{r=1}^\infty r a_r x^r$
- In (4) we use the linearity of the differential operator and since the geometric series is a function in $x$ the operator $yD_y$ transforms it to $0$.

Now we consider the the first summand of the RHS of (1).

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=1}^\infty&\sum_{g=1}^\infty rE(r-1,g)x^ry^g\\
> &=xD_x\sum_{r=1}^\infty\sum_{g=1}^\infty E(r-1,g)x^ry^g\\
> &=xD_x\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{g=1}^\infty E(r,g)x^{r+1}y^g\\
> &=xD_xx\left(G(x,y)-\sum_{r=0}^\infty E(r,0)x^r\right)\\
> &=xD_xx\left(G(x,y)-\sum_{r=0}^\infty r x^r\right)\\
> &=xD_xxG(x,y)-xD_xx^2D_x\frac{1}{1-x}\\
> \end{align*}

and  now the other summand of the RHS of (1).

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=1}^\infty&\sum_{g=1}^\infty gE(r,g-1)x^ry^g\\
> &=yD_y\sum_{r=1}^\infty\sum_{g=1}^\infty E(r,g-1)x^ry^g\\
> &=yD_y\sum_{r=1}^\infty\sum_{g=0}^\infty E(r,g)x^ry^{g+1}\\
> &=yD_yy\left(G(x,y)-\sum_{g=0}^\infty E(0,g)y^g\right)\\
> &=yD_y yG(x,y)
> \end{align*}

Putting all three expressions together we obtain

> \begin{align*}
> (xD_x+yD_y)&G(x,y)-(xD_x)^2\frac{1}{1-x}\\
> &=xD_xxG(x,y)-xD_xx^2D_x\frac{1}{1-x}+yD_y yG(x,y)\\
> (xD_x+yD_y&-xD_xx-yD_y y)G(x,y)\\
> &=\left((xD_x)^2-xD_xx^2D_x\right)\frac{1}{1-x}\\
> (xD_x(1-x)&+yD_y(1-y))G(x,y)=(xD_x)(1-x)(xD_x)\frac{1}{1-x}
> \end{align*}
>   and finally
>   \begin{align*}
> (xD_x(1-x)&+yD_y(1-y))G(x,y)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

We see $G(x,y)$ fulfills a linear differential equation in two variables. Please find   *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888659/looking-for-a-smart-way-to-solve-a-linear-pde-with-some-nice-symmetries/1890612#1890612)* a different way to proceed. But in fact we need not necessarily try to solve it, since we already know from  @MarkoRiedels *[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885371/can-double-generating-functions-be-used-to-solve-this/1885524#1885524)*:
\begin{align*}
E(r,g)=\frac{r}{g+1}
\end{align*}

> So, we do the easy way and calculate $G(x,y)$ this way
>
> \begin{align*}
> G(x,y)&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{g=0}^\infty E(r,g)x^ry^g\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{g=0}^\infty \frac{r}{g+1}x^ry^g\\
> &=\left(\sum_{r=0}^\infty rx^r\right)\left(\sum_{g=0}^\infty \frac{1}{g+1}y^g\right)\\
> &=xD_x\frac{1}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1}{y}\int\frac{1}{1-y}\,dy\\
> &=-\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{y}\left(\ln(1-y)+C\right)\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}

In order to determine the integration constant $C$ we evaluate $G(x,y)$ at $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> G\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)
> &=\sum_{r=0}^\infty r\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\sum_{g=0}^\infty \frac{1}{g+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^g
> =2\ln 4=4\ln 2
> \end{align*}
>   It follows together with (6)
>   \begin{align*}
> -4\left(\ln\frac{1}{2}+C\right)=4 \ln 2\qquad\longrightarrow\qquad C=0
> \end{align*}
>
> We finally conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> G(x,y)=-\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\cdot\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}
> \end{align*}
>   is a generating function for the sequence $\left(E(r,g)\right)_{r,g\geq 0}$ which fulfills the PDE (5).

**[Update 2016-08-13]:** According to OPs comments we extract the coefficient $E(r,g)$ from $G(x,y)$.

In order to do so, it's convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^r]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^r$ in a series $A(x)$.

> We obtain for $r,g\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> E(r,g)&=[x^ry^g]G(x,y)\\
> &=[x^ry^g]\left(-\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\cdot\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}\right)\\
> &=-[x^{r-1}y^{g+1}]\frac{\ln(1-y)}{(1-x)^2}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{r-1}y^{g+1}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{k}(-x)^k\sum_{j=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{j}y^j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{g+1}[x^{r-1}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+1}{1}x^k\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{r}{g+1}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$.
- In (2) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* and the use the series representation of $\ln(1-y)$.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $y^{g+1}$ and use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q$.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^{r-1}$.

Comment: This is very nice work. (+1). (Now that we have the holiday break not many answers collect votes.) What I am not sure about is that we have two different recurrence relations. I guess yours conditions on the first apple while mine conditions on the last? Can you add an explanation of this phenomenon? (The solution $R/(G+1)$ fits both.)

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks a lot, Marko. This approach is precisely OPs recurrence relation. Either picking a red apple with probability $\frac{r}{r+g}$ leaving $E(r-1,g)$ or picking a green apple with probability $\frac{g}{r+g}$ leaving $E(r,g-1)$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer After step (5), can that expression for $G$ be solved to yield $r/(g+1)$? One of the main reasons I had asked this question was to see if the closed form could be extracted from a double generating function approach. MarkoRiedel's answer is fantastic but I unfortunately do not understand most of it because it uses a lot of techniques I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: @user51819: Yes, I think it can be solved. I'll try to provide a solution tomorrow. Regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks for trying -- I'll keep an eye out on that other question

Comment: @user51819: I've provided a solution to the related question. Regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Assuming one takes your new approach and ends up with $G(x,y)=-\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\cdot\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}$, how does one turn that into $E(r,g) = \frac{r}{g+1}$?

Comment: @user51819: I've added a section at the end of my answer. Regards,

Comment: This is so cool. I wish I could upvote more. Thanks for this incredibly detailed set of answers. It'll take me some time to go through it all, but this is invaluable. Thanks so much.

Comment: @user51819: My pleasure! Thanks for your nice comment! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have $G$ green apples  and $R$ red apples and ask about the
number of red apples left when all green apples have been picked.

In computing  a recurrence  for the expectation  $E(R, G)$  we note
that if the  sequence of samples ends in a $G$  the expected number of
red apples  left is  zero. If it  ends in  a $R$ it  is one  more than
$E(R-1, G).$ We obtain the recurrence

$$E(R, G) = {R+G\choose R}^{-1} {R-1+G\choose R-1}
(1 + E(R-1, G))$$

where $E(0, G) = 0.$ Now

$${R+G\choose R}^{-1} {R-1+G\choose R-1} = 
\frac{(R-1+G)! R! G!}{(R+G)! (R-1)! G!}
= \frac{R}{R+G}$$

so this is

$$E(R, G) = \frac{R}{R+G}
(1 + E(R-1, G)).$$

We may drop the $G$ as an index variable as it never changes. We get

$$R E(R) + G E(R) = R + R E(R-1).$$

Introducing the generating function

$$F(z) = \sum_{R\ge 0} E(R) z^R$$

and multiplying by $z^R$ and summing over $R\ge 1$ we get

$$\sum_{R\ge 1} R z^R [z^R] F(z)
+ \sum_{R\ge 1} G z^R [z^R] F(z)
= \sum_{R\ge 1} R z^R
+ \sum_{R\ge 1} R z^R [z^{R-1}] F(z).$$

This is

$$z F'(z) + G F(z) = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} +
\sum_{R\ge 1} R z^R [z^{R-1}] F(z).$$

Solving the remaining term we get

$$\sum_{R\ge 2} R z^R [z^{R-1}] F(z)
= z^2 \sum_{R\ge 2} R z^{R-2} [z^{R-1}] F(z)
\\ = z^2 \sum_{R\ge 2} (R-1) z^{R-2} [z^{R-1}] F(z)
+ z^2 \sum_{R\ge 2} z^{R-2} [z^{R-1}] F(z)
\\ = z^2 F'(z) + z F(z).$$

This [ODE is linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) and we get

$$F'(z) + \frac{G-z}{z(1-z)} F(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^3}.$$

The integrating factor is

$$\exp((1-G)\log(z-1) + G\log(z))
= z^G (z-1)^{1-G}$$

and we obtain

$$F(z) = z^{-G} (z-1)^{G-1}
\left(\kappa - \int \frac{1}{(z-1)^3} z^G (z-1)^{1-G} dz\right)
\\ = z^{-G} (z-1)^{G-1}
\left(\kappa + \frac{1}{G+1} \frac{z^{G+1}}{(z-1)^{G+1}}\right)
\\ = \kappa \frac{1}{z} \left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{G-1}
+ \frac{1}{G+1} \frac{z}{(z-1)^2}.$$

It follows even without  determining $\kappa$ (the polynomial in front
contains only negative powers of $z$) that for $R\ge 0$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
[z^R] F(z) = \frac{1}{G+1} [z^R] \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}
= \frac{R}{G+1}.}$$

Comment: Nice answer! (+1)