# Looking for a smart way to solve a linear PDE with some nice symmetries

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

*Note:* This question is related with *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885371/can-double-generating-functions-be-used-to-solve-this/1887307#1887307)* and the PDE stated there in (5).

> Let $D_x:=\frac{d}{dx}$ and $D_y:=\frac{d}{dy}$ differential operators. We consider real-valued  functions $p(x),q(y)$  which obey the following linear differential equation in two variables
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(xD_x(1-x)+yD_y(1-y)\right)p(x)q(y)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> An equivalent representation of (1) with focus on the operators and separation of variables is e.g.
>   \begin{align*}
> q(y)\frac{x}{p(x)}D_x(1-x)p(x)+yD_y(1-y)q(y)=\frac{x}{p(x)}D_x(1-x)\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Note the symmetry between $p(x)$ and $q(y)$ with respect to the operator $xD_x(1-x)$ and $yD_y(1-y)$. The RHS is only dependent on $x$ while the right summand of the LHS is only dependent on $y$.

I think a feasible but rather cumbersome way is to consider the PDE as function in $x$, transform it in *[standard form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients)* and solve it using a multiplication factor $e^{\int f(x)}$ then do the same with respect to the other variable.

Since the PDE has such a striking symmetrical representation, I think there is a much shorter, smarter way to find the solutions. Any helpful ideas?

Comment: Isn't $D_{x} (1-x) = D_{y} (1-y) = -1$?  If so, how is this a differential equation at all?  Besides, for differential equations, Ordinary means one independent variable.  If you have partial derivatives, then it is a *partial* differential equation.

Comment: @avs I think it is meant in the sense of composition of operators, so $x D_x (1-x) f(x) = x D_x[(1-x)f(x)]$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer, it will help you get answers if you include the omitted (and necessary) parentheses.

Comment: @avs This is actually not that unusual notation, this is for instance routine notation in quantum mechanics. There you routinely see things like $\left ( x \frac{d}{dx} - \frac{d}{dx} x \right ) f$.

Comment: @Ian, ok.  I won't be responsible for the physicists' abuse of notation.:)

Comment: @avs Except I see it from mathematicians too. For example, "formally" we have $((e^{D \Delta t})f)(t)=f(t+\Delta t)$. Similarly $e^{t \Delta}$ is the time advancement operator for the heat equation, $e^{it \Delta}$ is the time advancement operator for the Schrodinger equation (in appropriate units) etc.

Comment: @avs: The  *[Pincherle derivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PincherleDerivative.html)*  is quite common in mathematics. In Ians first   example it is acting   as    commutator at the differential operator. See e.g. definition 2.9 in this introductory *[paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412233.pdf)* or section  2.4.1  in  *[this book](http://math.fau.edu/niederhausen/HTML/Research/UmbralCalculus/bookS2010.pdf)*.

Comment: @Ian: I agree with your comment and have added some info. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer which avoids at least partly lengthy calculations. Clever ideas of shorter      alternatives are of course welcome.

> We recall the recurrence relation stated in the *[related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885371/can-double-generating-functions-be-used-to-solve-this/1887307#1887307)*.
>
> \begin{align*}
> (r+g)E(r,g)&=rE(r-1,g)+gE(r,g-1)\qquad\qquad &r,g\geq 1\tag{1}\\
> E(r,0)&=r &r\geq 0\\
> E(0,g)&=0 &g\geq 0\\
> \end{align*}
>
> The corresponding generating function $G(x,y)$ defined as 
>   \begin{align*}
> G(x,y)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{g=0}^\infty E(r,g)x^ry^g\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> is a solution of the PDE 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(xD_x(1-x)+yD_y(1-y)\right)p(x)q(y)&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

In order to find a solution of the PDE we  take following approach. We assume $G(x,y)$ can be represented as product of functions $p(x)$ and $q(y)$
\begin{align*}
G(x,y)=p(x)q(y)\tag{4}
\end{align*}
We derive from (2) by setting $y=0$ and using the initial condition of $E(r,0)=r$ from (1)
\begin{align*}
G(x,0)&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty E(r,0)x^r=\sum_{r=0}^\infty r x^r\\
&= xD_x\frac{1}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align*}

> We conclude from (4)
>   \begin{align*}
> G(x,0)=p(x)q(0)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
> \end{align*}

Now  putting $p(x)=\frac{x}{q(0)(1-x)^2}$ in the differential equation and setting  $c:=\frac{1}{q(0)}$  we get
\begin{align*}
\left(xD_x(1-x)+yD_y(1-y)\right)p(x)q(y)&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
q(y)xD_x(1-x)p(x)+p(x)yD_y(1-y)q(y)&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
cq(y)xD_x\frac{1}{1-x}+c\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}yD_y(1-y)q(y)&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
cq(y)\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+c\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}yD_y(1-y)q(y)&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
cq(y)+cyD_y(1-y)q(y)&=1\\
cq(y)+cy((-1)q(y)+(1-y)q^\prime(y))&=1\tag{5}\\
\end{align*}

> We derive from (5) the linear ODE
>   \begin{align*}
> q^\prime(y)+\frac{c-y}{y(1-y)}q(y)&=\frac{c}{q(1-y)}
> \end{align*}
>
> With $e^{\int\frac{1}{y}dy}=e^{\ln y+c_0}=e^{c_0}y$ as integrating factor we obtain with *[standard techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients)*
>   \begin{align*}
> q(y)&=e^{-c_0}\frac{1}{y}\left(\int\frac{1}{1-y}\,dy+c_1\right)\\
> &=-\frac{1}{y}\ln(1-y)+\frac{c_2}{y}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>   with $c_0,c_1,c_2$ integration constants. It follows
>   \begin{align*}
> p(x)q(y)=\frac{1}{q(0)}\cdot\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\left(-\frac{1}{y}\ln(1-y)+\frac{c_2}{y}\right)
> \end{align*}

We finally need to determine the constants $q(0)$ and $c_2$. Since $q(0)\in\mathbb{R}$ it follows from (6) that $c_2=0$ to avoid division by zero. It also follows from (6)
\begin{align*}
q(0)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\left(-\frac{1}{y}\ln(1-y)\right)=1
\end{align*}

> We conclude the function $$G(x,y)=p(x)q(y)=-\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\cdot\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}$$         is a solution of the PDE (3).