# First Occurrence of a Type of Card in a Randomly Shuffled Deck

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random

Suppose that I have a deck of $T$ cards, with some set of size $X$ of them having some property.  If it helps you to think of a specific property, in a poker deck they could be all the hearts, in a MTG deck they could be mana cards, etc.

If I shuffle the deck, and pull cards one at a time into my "hand," what is the expected number of cards I need to draw to get one card of type $X$?  What sort of distribution do the first occurrences fall into.

Here is where I have gotten so far.  I may be on the completely wrong path, and I would appreciate being told so, even if you don't have the solution.

I tried to compute some sort of weighted average, multiplying each draw number by the chance that an $X$ card is drawn first on that turn.

The first draw has an $X\over T$ chance of being an $X$ card.  The first term in my sum is $$1 * \frac{X}{T}$$
The second draw has an $\frac{X}{T-1}$ chance of being an $X$ card, and there is a $1-{X\over T}$ chance that the first draw was not an $X$ card.  Now my sum reads: $$1 * \frac{X}{T} + 2 * (\frac{X}{T-1}) * ({1-{X\over T}}) $$
The chance that the the third draw is an $X$ card is $\frac{X}{T-2}$, the chance that the second draw was not the first occurrence is $(1- (\frac{X}{T-1}) * ({1-{X\over T}}))$.  This must be multiplied by the chance that draw #$1$ was not the first, which is $(1-\frac{X}{T})$.  All in all, the sequence with the third term reads:$$1 * \frac{X}{T} + 2 * (\frac{X}{T-1}) * ({1-{X\over T}} + 3 * (\frac{X}{T-2})(1- (\frac{X}{T-1})({1-{X\over T}}))(1-\frac{X}{T})$$  This is starting to look rather unwieldy.  I have no clue how to continue beyond this method, which I am pretty sure is wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Is there a general formula for the expected number of cards one must draw before the $n$th
 card of type $X$ is drawn?

^************************************************************************

EDIT:

The answer which Lulu gave does appear indeed to be correct.  I simulated via computer 100000 shuffles of a random deck and checked the first occurrence of a heart.  The average was $3.79157$.  $53 \over 14$ is $3.78571428571$.  Those numbers are close enough for me to be satisfied.

Comment: This is known as the [negative hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way:  Add an extra card $C$ to the deck and (for now) include it in the subset $X$.  Now arrange all the $T+1$ cards randomly in a circle.  By uniformity, we expect there to be $\frac {\#T+1}{\#X+1}$ cards in between each of the cards in the extended $X$ (counting the first element of $X$ that you reach).  Now remove $C$ from the circle and thereby define the start of the shuffled deck.  We then see that we expect $\frac {\#T+1}{\#X+1}$ until we reach the first element of $X$.

Sanity check:  $\#T=2,\#X=1$.  Then the two possible shuffles are $XY, YX$ so the answer is $\frac 32$ which matches the result given by the formula.  Similarly, for $\#T=n, \#X=1$, there are $n$ equally probable places for the unique $X$ to occur so the answer is $\frac {n(n+1)}2\Big / n=\frac {n+1}2$ which again matches the formula.

As another example, if $\#T=3,\#X=2$ then the possible shuffles are $XXY,XYX,YXX$ so the answer is $\frac 43$, again confirming the formula.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is very helpful.  A few questions though.  As you can see by my edit, your answer does seem to be correct.  However, I have a few questions.  Why can you define $C$ to be the start of the deck?  Couldn't it start in any of the $X$ positions?  Secondly, would the formula for the $n$th appearance be $n * \frac{T+1}{X+1}$?  Once again, thank you so much for your insightful, beautiful, and rapid answer!!

Comment: I can define any card in the circle to be the start, no problem.  The point of picking $C$ is that it preserves the symmetry.  The essential point of the argument is that symmetry tells us that the distance between any two elements of $X$ should be the same...but, unfortunately, the 'start point' and the 'end point' make it hard to use that principle.  Adding $C$ I restore the symmetry.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883733/what-is-the-expected-number-of-red-apples-left-when-all-the-green-apples-are-pic) is a variant of your question.  Thought I remembered a similar question a few years ago.  In my answer to that one I give an argument similar to the one I give here, but I also give a brute force calculation.  In another posted solution, you'll find a good argument that uses indicator variables.