# Probability with card deck flips

Tags: probability, expected-value, card-games

Here is my problem : we flip cards from a 52-card standard well-shuffled deck until the first club appears. I am looking to calculate the probability that the next card at the $k+1$th flip is also a club given that the $k$th flip is a club. Let $T$ be the flip on which we encounter the first club. Thanks to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122013/634171) I get
$$\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac{53}{14} \approx 3.7857$$
Now let $Y_n=1$ if we flip a club on the $n$th flip and $Y_n=0$ if we flip another suit. The number of clubs flipped amongst the first $n$ flips would be
$$C_n=\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$$
with $C_T=1$. After the $n$th flip, we have $\tilde{X}_n$ clubs remaining in the deck with proportion $X_n$:
$$X_n =\frac{\tilde{X}_n}{52 - n}, \ \tilde{X}_n = 13 - C_n$$
with $\tilde{X}_T=12$. So
$$X_T = \frac{13-C_T}{52 - T} = \frac{12}{52 - T}$$
We get
$$\mathbb{E}[X_T] = \frac{12}{52 - 3.7857} \approx 0.2489$$
the probability that the next card is a club. Can I use $\mathbb{E}[T]$ in the denominator like this? Thanks!

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Does  "The number of clubs flipped on the th flip" mean "the number of clubs flipped amongst the first $n$ flips?  And what is $X_n$?

Comment: As a general rule, $E\left( \frac 1Z\right)\neq \frac 1{E(Z)}$ if that is your question.

Comment: @lulu Yes the number of clubs amongst the first $n$ flips. $X_n$ is the proportion of clubs left in the deck. I'll make the edits. I am aware of this rule for expectation but I don't see how it doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: It is not super clear what you are asking. Are you trying to find the probability that the first club appears at position $k$ and that at position $k+1$ is also a club? Or are you trying to find the probability that position $k+1$ is a club given that position $k$ was the first club? Note that you have 13 clubs and 39 non-clubs, and once you found $k-1$ non-clubs, there are $39-k+1$ non-clubs and $13$ clubs, and once there $k$th card is the first club, you know that there are $39-k+1$ non clubs and $12$ clubs. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting an answer of $1/4$

Comment: @WillM. The probability that the $k+1$ position is a club given that position $k$ was the first club.

Comment: Leaving aside all the rest of the argument, you're defining a function ($X_T = f(T)$) of a random variable ($T$) and asking if $E[f(T)]=f(E[T])$.  In general, no, you can't compute the expected value of a function with only the expected value(s) of its argument(s).

Comment: @MatthewPilling how are you getting that? If we know the $k$th card is the first club then the conditional probability that $(k+1)$th card is also a club is $ \frac{12}{52-k}$. How are you approaching from there?

Comment: @MathLover Before the edit I thought the OP was asking for the probability of seeing another club immediately after observing the first club in this random process. So the probability is $$\sum_{k=1}^{40}\frac{\text{nPr}(39,k-1)}{\text{nPr}(52,k-1)}\cdot \frac{13}{52-(k-1)}\cdot \frac{12}{52-k}=\frac{1}{4}$$ Here, the index $k$ denotes the card flip in which the first club was observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the number of clubs ($k$).  Let $Q_n$ be the desired probability for a deck of $n \ge k$ cards with exactly $k$ clubs.  Either the first card is a club (with probability $k/n$), in which case the second card is a club with probability $(k-1)/(n-1)$; or else the first card is not a club (with probability $1-k/n$), and we've reduced to the $n-1$ case.   That is:
$$
Q_n=\frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}+\frac{n-k}{n}Q_{n-1},
$$
with the boundary condition that $Q_k=1$.

Playing with this recursion soon leads to the conjecture that $Q_n=k/n$, which may be proved by induction:
$$
Q_{n-1}=k/(n-1)\implies \\ Q_n=\frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}+\frac{n-k}{n}\cdot\frac{k}{n-1}=\frac{k(k-1)+(n-k)k}{n(n-1)}=\frac{-k+nk}{n(n-1)}=\frac{k}{n}.
$$
In other words, the card after the first club is exactly as likely to be a club as any other card in the deck.

Answer (score 2):

Mjqxxx has shown by a recursion that the probability that the card following the first club in the deck is also a club is $13/52$.  Here is another proof of that fact.

We start by asking a related question: What is the probability that the card following the first club in the deck is the ace of clubs?  There are $52!$ possible orderings of the deck, all of which we assume are equally likely.  We ask how many of those orderings have the ace of clubs immediately following the first club.  Suppose we remove the ace of spades from the deck and shuffle the remaining cards.  There are $51!$ possible orderings of the remaining cards, and in each case there is only one place to insert the ace of clubs so it is the next card after the first club; so there are $51!$ orderings in which the ace of clubs is the next card after the first club.  So the probability that the ace of clubs is the next card is
$$\frac{51!}{52!} = \frac{1}{52}$$
We can say the same about any particular club: the probability that it is the next card after the first club is $1/52$.  So the probability that the next card after the first club is a club is
$$13 \cdot \frac{1}{52} = \frac{13}{52}$$

Comment: +1, this is probably the best combinatorial explanation.